# Pandas Drop function for two columns not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, drop

I am  trying to drop two columns using Pandas Drop function. However, I am receiving error.
FYI I have printed column names of the data-frame. Why am I receiving such error?

In [284]: 
    Fulldf.columns

```
Out[284]:
Index(['PID', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodel', 'VeneerExterior', 'BsmtFinTp',
       'BsmtFinSqft', 'BsmtUnfinSqft', 'HeatingQC', 'FstFlrSqft', 'SecFlrSqft',
       'AbvGrndLiving', 'FullBathBsmt', 'HalfBathHouse', 'FullBathHouse',
       'BdrmAbvGrnd', 'RmAbvGrnd', 'Fireplaces', 'GarageTp', 'GarageCars',
       'GarageArea', 'WdDckSqft', 'OpenPrchSqft', 'LotArea', 'LotShape',
       'BldgTp', 'OverallQuality', 'OverallCondition', 'SalePrice'],
      dtype='object')

print(f'Total number of input variables to preprocess: {Fulldf.drop(['SalePrice', 'PID'], axis=1).shape[1]})
**strong text**
In [285]: 
  File "<ipython-input-287-7da1b9aca26a>", line 1
    print(f'Total number of input variables to preprocess: {Fulldf.drop(['SalePrice', 'PID'], axis=1).shape[1]})
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to use double quotes around the f-string because there are single quotes inside of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing single quotes and double-quotes. Can you try this?

```
print(f"Total number of input variables to preprocess: {Fulldf.drop(['SalePrice', 'PID'], axis=1).shape[1]}")
```